# My join sql query won't bring results

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

What could be wrong with my sql query here , I'd like to retrieve data from both tables meeting a WHERE condition

```
SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(i.sent_date) AS udate
FROM ibc_sent_history as i INNER JOIN
     ibc_messages as u
     ON i.msg_ids = u.id 
WHERE (i.sent_date >= '02-02-2013' AND i.sent_date <= '02-02-2014')
ORDER BY i.sent_date
LIMIT 200
```

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.

Comment: Maybe there are no rows in ibc_sent_history that match ibc_messages. Maybe there are no rows in ibc_sent_history where sent_date is between those two dates. We really can't help you w/o sample data.

Comment: What data type is `ibc_sent_history.sent_date`? Is it a DATE or a DATETIME? Also, are you looking for the first 200 messages in the date range?

Comment: I think the problem is the where clause  change  date to  '2003-02-02' and '2014-02-02' respectively

Comment: MySQL accepts '02-02-2014'? I live in a SQL Server world, alternative date formats are upsetting to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `ibc_sent_history.sent_date` datatype is DATETIME, here's a way to refactor this query. (This will work even if the datatype is DATE). You need to change your date input string format from `02-02-2013` to the more standard '2014-02-02` (YYYY-MM-DD).

```
    SELECT whatever, whatever
      FROM ibc_sent_history AS i 
INNER JOIN ibc_messages AS u ON i.msg_ids = u.id 
     WHERE i.sent_date >= '2013-02-02'
       AND i.sent_date <  '2014-02-02' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
  ORDER BY i.sent_date DESC
     LIMIT 200
```

I changed the ORDER BY to include DESC.  This is to return the most recent items, not the oldest. If that's not what you need, take off the DESC.

I changed the date formatting.

I changed the end of your selection range to

```
   i.sent_date <  '2014-02-02` + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

That's because

```
   i.sent_date <=  '2014-02-02`
```

will include items that occur precisely at midnight on 2-Feb-2014, but won't include any other items on that day. What you probably want are items that occurred up to but NOT including midnight on the next day.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know MySQL very well, but in SQL Fiddle when I run:

```
CAST('2014-02-02' AS DATE)
```

I get a date, when I run

```
CAST('02-02-2014' AS DATE)
```

I get `NULL`, so seems like your date format is wrong.

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/20242/0)

Comment: I'm still very suspicious of the line `i.msg_ids = u.id`.  Why would the `id` column be plural?  Otherwise, I would upvote you.